# Instrument limitations and capabilities

Tags: experimental-physics, instrument

What do we mean by instrument? Explain the limitation and capability of an instrument.

Answer (score 1):

You want a definition? I'm not big on definitions. Pretty much anything may be used as a physical instrument. Consider Richardson's use of pairs of parsnips floating on water as probes of turbulent diffusion. He tracked the distances between the parsnips as a function of time. Limitations and capabilities are specific to the instrument and its application. Parsnips float on water and are easy to see (capability), but can't be used for most other fluids, such as air (limitation).

Comment: This is a great eye opener, but I'm yet to understand what parsnips are and I wished I did, education down here is not as standardized and effective to prepare me for tasks that would require adequate and thorough study and understanding coupled with seasoned teacher to come up with this type of contribution. It has been hard all along but we remain focused!

Comment: @OyetundeDotun A parsnip is a vegetable. It looks like a white carrot. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsnip.